# How to RESTfully group a response for easier client consumption

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

Suppose I have two tables, Book and Author, where every Book has a foreign key to an author. The `/books/` endpoint returns a list of all books stored in the system. Now suppose that the client will consume this list, and group it by author. Would it be RESTful to have the server return the data nested and grouped by author so that the client doesn't need to? Is there a standard for requesting a grouping method for a response? (maybe something like `/books/?groupby=author`)

eg:

```
// flat
[
  {'title': 'Harry Potter', 'author': 'JK Rowling'},
  {'title': 'Harry Potter 2', 'author': 'JK Rowling'},
  {'title': 'Harry Potter 3', 'author': 'JK Rowling'},
  {'title': 'Lord of the Rings', 'author': 'J. R. R. Tolkien'},
]
```

vs

```
// nested
[
  {'author': 'JK Rowling', books: 
    [
      {'title': 'Harry Potter'},
      {'title': 'Harry Potter 2'},
      {'title': 'Harry Potter 3'},
    ]
  },
  {'author': 'J. R. R. Tolkien', books:
    [
      {'title': 'Lord of the Rings'}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I don't think there is a standard for such operation. The grouping can be done by client or it can be provided as another method as you mentioned.

Comment: Have a look JSON Pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect there to be an author resource with either a link to each book they've written or a link to a collection of all the books they've written. In either case, your API could support the query parameter "?embed=books", which populates the books in the JSON that's returned.

```
GET /authors/23
{
    "name": "JK Rowling",
    "_links": [
        "books": [
            "/books/4",
            "/books/532"
        ], ...
    ]
}

GET /authors/23?embed=books
{
    "name": "JK Rowling",
    "books": [
        {
            "title": "Harry Potter",
            "author": "/authors/23"
        },
        {
            "title": "Harry Potter 2",
            "author": "/authors/23"
        },
    ]
}
```

As an aside, in a real system, a book should be able to have more than one author.